# Unable to connect to bitbucket using git from jenkins from tomcat installation in windows

Tags: windows, git, tomcat, ssh, jenkins

I installed jenkins uploading the jenkins.war to my tomcat, in windows, and installed it the git plugin, I did all the procedures for the ssh key and I have been able to succesfully push and pull to my git repo in bitbucket from the cmd, but I haven't still been able to do it from jenkins, here are the weird stuff that happened to me:

- I can do push and pull and execute anything from git batch but to be able to do the same from the cmd I have to open it as administrator.
- The eval command doesn't work from the cmd.
- I get the "returned status code 128:" exception mentioned on the jenkins git plugin installation for windows manual, but instead of getting the "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" error I get "E:\Tomcat not recognized as an internal or external command"

Here's the exception:

```
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SRVSYMPHONY SSH
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:627)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:865)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:890)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1255)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1740)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:233)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: "E:\Tomcat" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Do you know whats happening to me?

Thanks

Comment: More fun: it works perfectly with github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to connect to my private repo in bitbicket I had to add the password to the url this way:

```
https://<user>:<pass>@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>.git
```

The answer was in this question:

[Using Jenkins with a private BitBucket Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208274/using-jenkins-with-a-private-bitbucket-git-repository)

Thanks

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? This is incredibly bad practice putting the password in the url. why not use ssh key?

Comment: the user and password are masked with jenkins credentials